# CNTK on Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, cntk

I have simple azure function

```
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(
        "%TopicName%",
        "%SubscriptionName%",
        Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
    Message input,
    ILogger logger)
{
    var device = CNTK.DeviceDescriptor.CPUDevice;
    Console.WriteLine(device);
}
```

Function uses simple call to CNTK library 2.6.
Function is targeting x64 platform.

```
<Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Everything is working locally, but when I deploy on azure it fails with an exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CNTK.CNTKLibPINVOKE' threw an exception. 
    ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception. 
    ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Cntk.Core.CSBinding-2.6.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.
```

Function app in azure is also set to 64bit platform.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask how are you publishing your app?

Comment: @RobErt actually try both way from devops as well as form VS locally, the result is the same. From devops I dotnet publish -p:Platform=x64 -c Release -o ....

Comment: Check this regarding dependencies: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/3030

Comment: It’s possible the native dependencies that his is looking for aren’t where functions expects to see them.  Is there an easy way you can send me a repro so I can try it out and see what could be going on?  Jehollan@microsoft.com

Comment: @RobErt yes, your link solve the problem..thanks, but this is really strange

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov nice to hear:) Yep it's that's this extra price for enterprise solutions:D